# Какие библиотеки установлены на Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 для С++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Какие библиотеки установлены на Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 для С++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Справочные материалы по библиотекам Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/52cs05fz.aspx)

> Описание библиотек Visual C++ содержится в следующих документах.

Конкретно список библиотек вы можете найти в папках Visual Studio.